# How to break on / watch for EJB deadlocks in Payara?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, concurrency, ejb, payara

As established by the [EJB spec](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/enterprise-beans/4.0/jakarta-enterprise-beans-spec-core-4.0#concurrent-access-timeouts), the access timeout for an EJB locked for access on concurrency management can be set via `@AccessTimeout` annotation.

Without this annotation specifying otherwise, the timeout in Payara for accessing a locked EJB is infinite.

This is pretty inconvenient because it generates no stack or log traces whatsoever on the application server log during a deadlock. It just hangs the dependent services, making them unresponsive.

Our team wants to modify this default in our development server, to have the beans throw a `jakarta.ejb.ConcurrentAccessException` every time a bean or bean method is locked for access for a longer time than it should.

I know from working with JBoss/Wildfly back in the day that this should be possible via [application server configuration](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/jboss_enterprise_application_platform/6/html/administration_and_configuration_guide/set_default_session_bean_access_timeout_values1). We have not been able to find related documentation to do this for Payara/Glassfish asadmin, though.

Is there a way to set a default concurrent EJB access timeout on Payara? If not, what would be a viable alternative to easily identify deadlocks as they happen in our development server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently there's this nice Payara [cdi-event-bus-notifier](https://docs.payara.fish/community/docs/Technical%20Documentation/Payara%20Server%20Documentation/Logging%20and%20Monitoring/Notification%20Service/Overview.html#cdi-event-bus-notifier) we could set up to collect metrics on hogging & stuck threads, which we could then set alerts on:

https://blog.payara.fish/the-health-check-service-in-depth-payara-server

This would satisfy the needs for our use case even better than setting a default access timeout (e.g. we could even enable it on production, eventually).

Nevertheless it would be nice to know if there is a possibility to set a default access timeout (which, for example, could allow us to more conveniently look at the server logs rather than the metrics when working on a local dev deployment).